# Количество входных процессов (EP)

Tags: php, laravel, сервер, hosting

Прошу совета. Сделан сайт на laravel - небольшой магазин\каталог. В каталоге выводятся карточки товаров с фотографиями - 25 товаров на страницу = 25 фото. При открытии страницы загружается страница. А потом подгружаются 25 фотографий.

Проблема в том, что на хостинге стоит ограничение на количество входных процессов (EP) - 20. Как результат, я упираюсь в это ограничение и часть фото вообще не грузится - Resource Limit Is Reached.

Собственно вопрос - это нормально? Или я что-то не так сделал на сайте? Ссылки на фото имеют вид

```
<img src="https://example.com/images/medium_square/ReGuHeFVgOWFjB08MNqqd4LiesJI73ohjE6cDBe3.jpeg">
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что решения:

- другой тариф с большим EP, выделенный сервер, VPS, VDS и другое, где нет такого ограничения вообще
- последовательная загрузка фотографий с помощью js
- перенос фотографий на другой сервер или в облако типа S3

Я сделал последовательную загрузка фотографий с помощью js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но не покидает ощущение, что что-то не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам лучше изучить это, связавшись с техподдержкой вашего поставщика услуг, либо почитав их документацию по этому вопросу.